# Delete line breaks at the beginning of a page automatically on MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, shortcuts

Let's say there is a line break at the last line of page 1, then I add some text before the line break and this line break becomes the first line of page 2, then there is also text after on page 2 and the next pages.

Is there a way to automatically delete this line break (and any empty lines before the first word of page 2) as it comes before any text on the page? Or can I create a macro for that purpose?

I would like to have no line breaks or empty spaces as the first line of every page of my document but only text.

I'm using MS Office Pro Plus 2016 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically delete this line break (and any empty lines before the first word of page 2) as it comes before any text on the page? Or can I create a macro for that purpose?

No, there is no automatic way for that. Also Word VBA is not correctly aware of pagination, so it can't solve this problem.

What you can do - actually best practice - is not to use empty paragraphs. Instead of empty paragraphs create style with bigger space after the paragraph, that will never be located on top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's seems ok, the thing is that it adds up space after each paragraph, and the spacing takes "too much" of the page. Also if I style the end of a paragraph with a bigger space at the end of a page, and I add text and sentences before the said paragraph, the empty lines become inconsistent height-wise.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you're asking, you would like to delete all manual page breaks and all empty paragraphs.  This can be done through Find and Replace.  I'm sure someone else can come up with a solution that's more elegant, but this one seems to do what you want to do:

IMPORTANT:  First of all, Save your document with a different title!  The Find and Replace function can give unexpected results sometimes, so be sure to do this with a copy of your document, not the original.  Also, recommend you turn on paragraph symbols.

1. Open the Find and Replace window.
2. Type a caret followed by a lower case m in the Search line (^m).
3. Type a caret followed by a lower case p in the Replace line (^p).

This tells it to find each manual page break and replace it with an empty paragraph.

4. Click the Replace button to go to the first manual page break.
5. Click Replace to replace that first page break and go to the next.
6. Continue clicking Replace to go through them one-by-one, or Replace All to get all of them in the document.

The next thing you want to do is find all the empty paragraphs and replace them with basically nothing.

7. In the Search line, type in a caret followed by a lower case p, and type it twice (^p^p).
8. In the Replace line, type a single instance of ^p.

This will find every case of 2 sequential paragraphs and change it to one paragraph. We haven't got to the "nothing" part yet.

9. Click Replace to take you to the first 2 sequential paragraphs.
10. Continue clicking Replace to go through them one-by-one, or Replace All to get all of them.
11. You will go through the entire document, but when you're through you'll likely still have empty paragraphs.
12. Repeat steps 9 through 11 until the Search/Replace dialog box says you have 0 replacements.  This is where we've replaced the empty paragraphs with basically nothing.

A little tedious and time-consuming, but still faster than deleting them all manually.

Last thing is to turn off the empty space at the top of the page when a new paragraph has space above it (directions are for MS Word Windows 2016 and 365):

13. Go to File > Options > Advanced > scroll to the bottom of the options.
14. Check the box that says Suppress extra line spacing at bottom of page.
15. Check the box that says Suppress extra line spacing at top of page.
16. Click OK.